# Text file import and how to manipulate select rows and columns into different arrays and do calculations

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have limited experience in ipython and I work in a research lab. We run an experiment that outputs a .txt file once it is finished taking results. Up until now due to the format of the .txt file we need first copy and paste into an excel sheet and then do a bunch of annoying copying and pasting in order to get the different rows in the order we want.

The only important columns that we need are the "well" column and the "Abs" column. I need to find a way so that I can identify the Abs numbers with with its associated well identity. The end goal is for me to write a script doing some super simple math manipulations such as average well H01 and H02 so that I can subtract that number from the rest of the wells.

That might have been confusing but let me know if you have any questions or ideas on places to start other than reading in the file (which is all I am able to do right now). Your help would be greatly appreciated!

[Text file produced by machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbtkF.png)

Code that I have attempted (not very much)

from **future** import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
%matplotlib inline

data = np.loadtxt('python test file.txt',skiprows= 3, usecols=(1,7), dtype= str, unpack=True)
print (data)

This is what is printed...

[["b'A01'" "b'B01'" "b'C01'" "b'D01'" "b'E01'" "b'F01'" "b'G01'" "b'H01'"
  "b'H02'" "b'G02'" "b'F02'" "b'E02'" "b'D02'" "b'C02'" "b'B02'" "b'A02'"
  "b'A03'" "b'B03'" "b'C03'" "b'D03'" "b'D04'" "b'C04'" "b'B04'" "b'A04'"]
 ["b'6'" "b'6'" "b'5.3501'" "b'6'" "b'6'" "b'6'" "b'3.59128'" "b'0.177349'"
  "b'0.174828'" "b'3.42995'" "b'6'" "b'5.37723'" "b'5.39004'" "b'5.54484'"
  "b'6'" "b'6'" "b'5.35271'" "b'3.78453'" "b'5.41057'" "b'6'" "b'6'"
  "b'5.3402'" "b'3.04992'" "b'6'"]]

Comment: Your file looks like tab separated csv. I would suggest you to use pandas read_csv function to read file as DataFrame. The code will look like ```pd.read_csv(file_path, sep="\t", skiprows=2). It pandas DataFrame will also support other operations like averaging, sum etc. If would be easier if you can paste some initial part of you file in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've managed to completely understand your question. First, when you are reading the file, you are specifying that each element is a string (`dtype=str`). However, you have one column of strings and one column of floats. Then, you are also using the argument `unpack=True` which means that numpy will output more than one array, but you are collecting only `data`. If this is not clear, don't worry, it will become clearer with the example below.

Another thing is that in Python the default is to use unicode for strings, and that is why you are seeing the `b` in front of the values that you are reading.

To import the columns you want, you can do the following:

```py
well, absorption = np.loadtxt('file.txt', 
                              skiprows=3, 
                              usecols=(1,7), 
                              dtype={
                                  'names': ('Well', 'Abs'), 
                                  'formats': ('U3', 'f4')}, 
                              unpack=True)
```

In the command above, pay attention to how you specify the `formats`. For example, the `f4` means you are going to grab a float with 4 decimals. If you would change it to `f2`, you would get less decimals, etc. Be careful with what you need. The same with the `U3` meaning that you are grabbing 3 unicode characters, but you may need something different.

Now, you wanted to work on your data. First, you need to find what data lines correspond to H01 and H02. You can do the following:

```py
blanks_indexes = np.where(np.logical_or(well=='H01', well=='H02'))
```

And if you want to calculate the average:

```py
abs_blanks = np.mean(absorption[blanks_indexes])
```

And simply:

```
corrected_abs = absorption - abs_blanks
```

I think this can get you started. Depending on where are you coming from, you may check [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), which is a great tool to work with tabular data like the one you have, but you have to learn it, so it is up to you to decide whether to invest the time or not.

Comment: This was super helpful and put me off to a great start I will definitely be able to work off of this a lot. Just a couple questions. When I used the line of code you wrote to read in the file it is throwing me a syntax error right where it says unpack=True and I am not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Also looking at the way you defined the blanks as blanks_indexes, would I be able to define any sample (as in two wells side by side so we can do it in duplicate i.e. wells A03 and A04 being the sample sample) like that in an array and manipulate it? such as subtract the blank average from both wells in the sample (A03-blank, A04-blank). please let me know when you get the chance!

Comment: There was a ``}`` missing, but it is fixed now. Regarding the second question, I don't fully understand it, and most likely it does not fit in Stack Overflow. I would suggest to try to ask in: https://forum.pythonforthelab.com/